# Trouble including external jar required for an import in a src/java/{somename}.java in a grails-app( grails2.0)

Tags: grails, connector, dhtmlx

I need a DHTMLXCONNECTOR.jar (a connector executable jar) in my grails app to use with my application otherwise i get errors like :

```
 error compiling in javac connot find symbol : import com.dhtmlx.connector
```

please help !I tried grails install-dependencies dhtmlxconnector .. Is it,  that i need to edit the buildconfig file ? like something similar to uncommenting runtime for mysql ?
(grails 2.0.1)

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem..me too is facing such a problem..please help me..

Answer (score 0):

Add your dependency to the `dependencies` section of `BuildConfig.groovy`.
For example to add the dependency with

- groupId: `org.jsoup`
- artifactId: `jsoup`
- version: `1.6.1`

---

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.6.1'
}
```